# Precompiling assets for a multi-homed Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, sprockets

I have a multi-homed Rails 3.2 application where each "home" has its own skin. The assets for these are precompiled using a custom Rake task:

```
require "fileutils"

namespace :assets do
  namespace :precompile do
    task :homes, [:short_name] => ["assets:environment"] do |t, args|
      include Sprockets::Helpers::RailsHelper
      homes = args.short_name ? home.where(:short_name => args.short_name) : home.all
      homes.each do |home|
        appenv = Rails.application.assets
        appenv.clear_paths
        paths = [
          "app/assets/homes/#{home.short_name}/images",
          "app/assets/homes/#{home.short_name}/stylesheets",
          "app/assets/homes/#{home.short_name}/javascripts"
        ]
        paths.each{|x| appenv.append_path x}

        config = Rails.application.config
        config.assets.prefix = home.short_name
        config.assets.digest = true
        config.assets.debug = false
        config.assets.compress = true
        target = File.join(Rails.public_path, config.assets.prefix)

        puts "Compiling assets for #{home.name} into #{target}"
        Sprockets::StaticCompiler.new(appenv, target, ["*"], digest: true, manifest: true).compile
        Sprockets::StaticCompiler.new(appenv, target, ["*"], digest: false, manifest: true).compile
      end
    end
  end
end
```

This Rake task takes an optional "home" parameter, and will only compile the assets for that "home" if supplied - if not it loops through all "homes" and compiles the assets for each one:

```
rake assets precompile:homes[my_home]
```

or

```
rake assets precompile:homes
```

In my ApplicationController I set the asset paths dynamically like this:

```
MyApp::Application.config.assets.prefix = @home.short_name
MyApp::Application.config.assets.digests = YAML.load_file(File.join(Rails.public_path, @home.short_name, "manifest.yml"))
```

This works very well - as long as I run the Rake task in the development environment - but when run in production I get an error when trying to modify the environment, on `appenv.clear_paths`:

```
$ rake assets precompile:homes RAILS_ENV=production

TypeError: can't modify immutable index
/var/rails/MyApp/vendor/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.3/lib/sprockets/index.rb:80:in `expire_index!'
/var/rails/MyApp/vendor/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.3/lib/sprockets/trail.rb:49:in `clear_paths'
/var/rails/MyApp/lib/tasks/assets.rake:10:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>
```

I understand that this is because Sprockets uses a different object to represent the appenv in production, in development this is the full environment (Sprockets::Environment), whereas in production it is a reduced and restricted subset (Sprockets::Index) which is read-only. But this leads to a catch 22: in order to be able to set the asset paths dynamically in the task I need to run it in development, but in order to compress and minify the assets, and to get the digests to work, I have to run it in production. As you can see I have tried to force it to compress and generate digests also in development, but this seems to have no effect:

```
    config.assets.digest = true
    config.assets.debug = false
    config.assets.compress = true
```

I have been trying to find a solution to this for a couple of days now but haven't been able to come up with anything that works - not helped by having an awfully bad cold and generally feeling a bit worn out :( It seems to me this should be a fairly common scenario, so I'm hoping someone here will know what to do...

Comment: and what if you set a `RAILS_GROUPS=assets` environment var?

`rake assets precompile:homes RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets` IDK if this will work, but RAILS_GROUPS var affects the precompile behaviour.

Comment: alternatively you can create a new environment (e.g. `config/environments/deploy-assets.rb`) copied from production and precompile with it (`rake assets precompile:homes RAILS_ENV='deploy-assets'`).

Comment: @Daniel: Setting `RAILS_GROUPS=assets` is a great suggestion which makes a lot of sense - alas the error remains the same. I do have an "assets" group in the Gemfile, which inlcudes "sass-rails" and "uglifier" (Sprockets itself being bundled with Rails).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I appreciate that Rails 3.2 is a little past its sell-by-date, what with [Rails 5 having been announced](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2014/8/20/Rails-4-2-beta1/#maintenance-consequences-and-rails-5-0) and all, but until someone donates a month's worth of spare time (contact me for details) I'll have to keep this thing running. Luckily, once my cold had cleared, it wasn't too hard to solve the problem I was having - here's what the fixed Rake task looks like:

```
require "fileutils"

namespace :assets do
  namespace :precompile do
    task :homes, [:short_name] => ["assets:environment"] do |t, args|
      include Sprockets::Helpers::RailsHelper
      homes = args.short_name ? home.where(:short_name => args.short_name) : home.all
      homes.each do |home|
        appenv = Rails.application.assets
        appenv.clear_paths
        paths = [
          "app/assets/homes/#{home.short_name}/images",
          "app/assets/homes/#{home.short_name}/stylesheets",
          "app/assets/homes/#{home.short_name}/javascripts"
        ]
        paths.each{|x| appenv.append_path x}

        config = Rails.application.config
        config.assets.prefix = home.short_name
        config.assets.digest = true
        target = File.join(Rails.public_path, config.assets.prefix)

        puts "Compiling assets for #{home.name} into #{target}"
        Sprockets::StaticCompiler.new(appenv, target, ["*"], digest: false, manifest: false).compile
        Sprockets::StaticCompiler.new(appenv, target, ["*"], digest: true, manifest: true).compile
      end
    end
  end
end
```

This differs from what I previously had in a couple of ways:

- The `debug` and `compress` options are no longer set on `Rails.application.assets` before running the compilations as these apparently had no effect.
- The order in which the digest/non-digest assets are compiled has been switched, so that the digest assets are created *after* the non-digest ones.

The second change solves the missing digests problem, and with the following in `environments/development.rb` assets are minified and CSS files no longer contain SASS line number comments:

```
config.assets.debug = false
config.assets.compress = true
```

So it's all working pretty much exactly how I wanted, as long as it's run in the development environment, which is fine - problem *solved*.

**Edit:** So, I noticed that asset references inside SCSS files were not being given a digest filename, and some further testing showed that `config.assets.digest = true` *does* need to be set after all. The code above has been updated to reflect this. Otherwise `digest_assets` is false when actionpack/lib/sprockets/helpers/rails_helper.rb checks `if digest_assets && options[:digest] != false`